# EasyMock create mock fails for a class with a clone() method

Tags: mocking, easymock

I am having an issue when trying to mock a class which has a clone() method, which creates a deep copy of the object. When i remove this method, mocking works fine.

```
public class ConcreteClass implements Iterable<Record> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Record> iterator() { 
    }

    public ConcreteClass clone() {
        ConcreteClass copy = new ConcreteClass();
        return copy;
    }
```

Creating a mock of above class using `EasyMock.createMock(ConcreteClass.class)` fails with following exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15092

    at net.sf.cglib.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.BridgeMethodResolver.resolveAll(BridgeMethodResolver.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:911)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:498)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:175)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:129)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:103)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:94)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock(EasyMock.java:136)
    at com.test.Test(Test.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

However when i remove clone() method I can create a mock successfully.
I am using EasyMock 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the complete EasyMock version would be a good idea. I just tried with EasyMock 4.0.2, it worked without any issue. So upgrading might be the answer.

Please note that `clone()` is a special name for Java. The user will normally expect the class to be `Cloneable` and the override to return `Object` (for a lot of legacy reasons) instead of the actual class. The implementation should call `super.clone()`. If I was you, I would rename the method to `copy()`.